# WCF REST service returning empty class

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have the following service:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IConnectionService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetState", BodyStyle = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped), Description("")]
        State GetState();
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class State
    {
        [DataMember]
        public bool Client_1_Ok { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool Client_2_Ok { get; set; }
    }
```

on my server side I create a new instance of the State class and set the variables just to see if they reach the client as it is supposed to

```
    public class Server : IConnectionService
    {
        public State GetState()
        {
            State tempState = new State();

            tempState .Client_1_Ok = true;
            tempState .Client_2_Ok = true;

            return tempState ;
        }
```

an the client side I open a channel and call the GetState on my server side.. so far so good

```
        private IConnectionService ConnectionChannel = null;

        public State GetState()
        {
            try
            {
                ConnectionFactory = new WebChannelFactory<IConnectionService>(new Uri("http://" + this.HostIpAddress + ":" + this.Port.ToString() + "/Tes"));
                this.ConnectionChannel = ConnectionFactory.CreateChannel();

                State returnvalue = this.ConnectionChannel.GetState();

                return state;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Communication error
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                try { this.ConnectionChannel.Close(); }
                catch { this.ConnectionChannel.Abort(); }

                //dispose of the connection channel
                this.ConnectionChannel.Dispose();
                this.ConnectionChannel = null;
            }
        }
```

But the GetState call from the client side always returns an instance of State where the booleans are false.

In similar posts peaople forgot to add the DataContract and DataMember attributes but I made sure to add these. The solution is probably something small and stupid but I can't see where I messed up

Comment: Does your config has to be revisited based on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910199/wcf-rest-service-not-returning-data-in-browser ?

Comment: Why is this GET a POST?

Answer (score 0):

The servicecontract didn't have a RequestFormat. In my case it needed WebMessageFormat.Json

My ServiceContract now looks like this:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IConnectionService
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetState", BodyStyle = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json), Description("")]
        State GetState();
    }
```